# The box with the settings is not showing up when i add a new object

Tags: objects, interface

When i add a box, plane, cylinder etc., the box on the bottom left (screenshot) is not showing up. What shoud i turn on to get that box when i create a new object?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's called the *Adjust Last Operation* menu.
just enable it in *View > Adjust Last Operation*

Also if you press <kbd>F9</kbd> it will pop up wherever your cursor is.

[image]