# How to scale a mesh selection to exact dimensions?

Tags: interface, scale

(Absolute Blender beginner...)

I've imported an obj model and I'm trying to scale up 2 specific regions of it. I've selected one area of the model that I want and have figured out how to scale it with the scale tool.

But since I need to replicate the exact scaling parameters in a few different selections, I'm trying to find out how to edit the scaling properties directly rather than dragging around with the mouse.

Been digging through docs, youtube videos, and UI but haven't been able to find out how to show the scaling options window. Could someone point out how to display the options window?

Have attached a screenshot of where I'm currently at.
[image]

Comment: Hello :). The scaling options window can be [enabled like this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/161384/78972). Scaling to precise proportions is also possible, I'll add an answer later.

Comment: The propoertional scale stays the same or can be looked up in the dialog JACHYM linked. To scale by a constant you can simply type the number e.g. S X 0.16 Enter to scale by 16% along the x axis.

Comment: @ᴊᴀᴄʜʏᴍᴍɪᴄʜᴀʟ thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for. I'm really liking how intuitive most of 2.8 is overall.