# How would I bevel complicated corner?

Tags: mesh, edges, bevel

I'm curious how I would bevel this complicated corner to the red lines.  I just can't figure it out so any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: How would I bevel this to the red lines?]

Comment: That's a situation you do not want to have :D This is not suitable geometry to use the bevel function. You could sculpt it or delete the geometry there and recreate it with a bevel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use proportional editing to 'round' such corner.

1. Select the edge and move it inwards (this will be the bevel radius)
2. Enable Proportional editing set to *Sharp*
3. Use the Size slider to adjust the influence

[image]

Comment: Jachym Michal thank you.  When I select the move gizmo I don't get that move menu box to pop up.  Any ideas?

Comment: Hey :). Perhaps this could help: [The box with settings is not showing up](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/161381/78972)

Comment: worked like a charm!  Thanks